# alternative for executing <script> at end of document body

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, katex

I am trying to get [KaTeX autorendering](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/tree/master/contrib/auto-render) to work with Sphinx, but it is very difficult within the Sphinx framework, because of the way templating works (I'm doing this work in the Sphinx extension rather than the theme) to add the lines KaTeX suggests to the end of the `<body>` element:

```
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    renderMathInElement(document.body);
  </script>
</body>
```

Is there a viable alternative to run Javascript in the `<head>` element instead (this is much easier), and add an `onload` or other event handler to run `renderMathInElement(document.body)` ?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/4875631) help you?

Comment: Alternative would be to make a separate js file that the HTML links to outside it.

Comment: You could use the `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` events.

Comment: I think FrankerZ's comment (`DOMContentLoaded`) will do, I just didn't know what it was called or what the subtleties were between `document.onLoad` and `window.onLoad`

Answer (score 0):

For all the wrong reasons, I once loaded a script with jQuery on event. It was a little tricky to avoid the script tag to trigger an error, but some creative splicing did the job.

```
var extenalScript = "<"+"script"+">"+"renderMathInElement(document.body);"+"<"+"/script"+">";
$('body').append(extenalScript);
```